# Remove special character tag from my string

Tags: php

I am trying to remove all tag from my string and display it to the user
My string is :

```
$abc='<ol><li>nice products </li></ol>';
echo  html_entity_decode($abc);
echo  htmlspecialchars_decode($abc);
```

But it is not removing these tag.can any one suggest me what I should use.
I am currently using php version 5.6

Comment: Maybe you can use strip_tags: http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Try: `strip_tags($abc);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to remove all html tags use `strip_tags()` function:

```
$abc = '<ol><li>nice products </li></ol>';
echo strip_tags($abc);
```

Comment: So @phenix can post this as answer.

Comment: @SumitKumar what means "didn't work", can you write little more? 
working [demo here](https://eval.in/573097)

Comment: it doesn't remove these tag

Comment: @SumitKumar show your code with `strip_tags()` function

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags() should solve your problem.

It is working in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ . Like you said PHP 5.6
 environment.
Copied your string

```
$abc='<ol><li>nice products </li></ol>';
echo strip_tags($abc);
```

Result is : nice products